# SQL - Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, database

Assume I have this PHP code:

```
    $emailCheck = $_POST['emailCheck'];
    echo "Checking: " . $emailCheck; // Checking: test@test.net
    var_dump($stmt);
    $sql = "SELECT id, email FROM members WHERE email=?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $emailCheck);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($m_id, $m_email);
    $stmt->execute();
```

and my database:

[image]

as you can see, I can get it from PHPMyAdmin. However, PHP page is another story because I get:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in...

with the offending line being:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, email FROM members WHERE email=?";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Upon doing `var_dump($stmt);`, I got:

```
object(mysqli_stmt)[4]
  public 'affected_rows' => null
  public 'insert_id' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'param_count' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'errno' => null
  public 'error' => null
  public 'error_list' => null
  public 'sqlstate' => null
  public 'id' => null
```

edit: I got downvoted despite being as descriptive as I could. Classy.

Comment: @usermesam0023 ... yes. The picture above shows that....

Comment: try to dump value of $stmt? I think you might be getting false there.

Comment: You never test if your prepare fails - `if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(...)) {  $stmt->bind_param(...);  ... } else { printf("Error Message: %s\n", $mysqli->error); }`

Comment: @Sean Just did that and the Error message comes back empty...

Comment: @almasshaikh I did that and I got `boolean false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure your mysql connection is OK with `$mysqli->stat()`.

Answer (score 1):

`$stmt` can probably false.

Try this code:

```
    $emailCheck = $_POST['emailCheck'];
    echo "Checking: " . $emailCheck; // Checking: test@test.net
    $sql = "SELECT id, email FROM members WHERE email=?";
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $emailCheck);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($m_id, $m_email);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    else {
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
```

Comment: If you use "s", then the generated query will be something like:

"SELECT id, email FROM members WHERE email="s"";
-which ends up with an error in mysql.